# SQL LIKE returns wrong results and double rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-like

My query (this gives me a correct output)

```
SELECT      
   CONCAT(Category.CategoryName, ': ',Product.ProductName) AS SearchOut,
 Product.ProductID
FROM Product
    ,Category
    ,ParentCategory
    ,ProductCategory
WHERE ParentCategory.ParentCatID = Category.CategoryID
   AND Category.CategoryID = ProductCategory.CategoryID 
   AND ProductCategory.ProductID = Product.ProductID
```

But this going to be a search function so I want my `LIKE` there.

This is my `LIKE` SQL continuing from the first one

```
   AND Category.CategoryName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR Product.ProductName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR Product.Description LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR Product.Artnr LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR ParentCategory.ParentCatName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

Then the query is all messed up, all is wrong and the rows is more then double.

Like on extra row for every row that exists or something.

I also tried to first code snippet in Joins, but it was all wrong to.

The `Product` is only supposed to show up once in the results except the ones that actually exists in more than one category, but then you see that because `categoryname` and `productname` is contatenated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style is discouraged with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago) - use the **proper** ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your condition lacks parentheses. It should be as follows:

```
AND (Category.CategoryName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
    OR Product.ProductName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
    OR Product.Description LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
    OR Product.Artnr LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
    OR ParentCategory.ParentCatName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%')
```

A good way to avoid situations like this is to switch to ANSI joins. This way your join conditions would not be mixed with filter conditions, making parentheses unnecessary:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Category.CategoryName, ': ',Product.ProductName) AS SearchOut
     ,Product.ProductID
FROM Product
JOIN ProductCategory ON ProductCategory.ProductID = Product.ProductID
JOIN Category ON Category.CategoryID = ProductCategory.CategoryID
JOIN ParentCategory ON ParentCategory.ParentCatID = Category.CategoryID
WHERE Category.CategoryName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR Product.ProductName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR Product.Description LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR Product.Artnr LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
   OR ParentCategory.ParentCatName LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
```

Comment: Try to work out the order of the `JOINS`, now the conditions don't match up.